# Why can’t I enter a directory when I have the right to?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

My distribution is the latest Gentoo. 
I have a directory called `music` which belongs to `qdii:commun` and which octal access rights are "2070", that is: all permissions are granted to the group (`commun`), but none to the user (`qdii`).

Last element: `qdii` belongs to `commun`.

```
qdii@ks396822 ~/commun $ chmod g+wrxs music/
qdii@ks396822 ~/commun $ cd music/
-bash: cd: music/: Permission denied
```

What’s happening?

**EDIT:**

```
qdii@ks396855 ~/commun $ ls -l
total 4
d---rws--- 2 qdii commun 4096 Jun 10 20:26 music
qdii@ks396855 ~/commun $ cd music/
-bash: cd: music/: Permission denied
qdii@ks396855 ~/commun $ groups qdii
wheel commun qdii
```

Comment: Post the output of the commands that prove your assumptions.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: here you are. I understand your request, but I have checked multiple times that I did not make a rookie mystake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user permissions have higher priority than the group permissions. Otherwise, it would not be possible to create a file that only the owner can access, but the group can not.

Comment: Yet, it's confusing : being the owner of that directory here, prevents me from opening it. If it had been owned by anyone else, I would be able to open it.